# Css Responsive design for mobile doesn't scroll down

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design

I am trying to use responsive css for some resoultions with media queries. The problem is mobile screen doesn't scroll down with the 320x480 resolution below. Any ideas why it is NOT scrolling down?

Best Regards.

```
/*======================== RESPONSIVE ========================*/
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height:480px) and (orientation: portrait) {
    body {
        font-size: 14px;
        border: 0 solid transparent;

    }

    h1, .intro h1 {
        font-size: 32px;
    }

    h2 {
        font-size: 28px;
    }

    h3 {
        font-size: 24px;
    }

    h4 {
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    .intro p {
        font-size: 14px;
    }

        .intro p span {
            width: 60px;
        }

    section h1 {
        font-size: 2.5em;
        margin-top: 0;
    }

    .logo {
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 auto 40px auto;
        font-family: ethnocentric, sans-serif;
        font-size: 55px;
    }

    .pics {
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    .col-md-3 {
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    .partnerRow {
        padding-left: 0;
        text-align: center;
        margin-left: 10%;
        margin-right: 10%;
    }

    ul, ol {
        padding: 0;
    }
}
```

Here is the markup:

```
    <!-- Overlay -->
    <div id="firefly" class="bg-overlay">
        <canvas id="star-canvas"></canvas>    
    </div>
    <!-- End Overlay -->
    <div class="lang">
        <a href="#turkish" onclick="window.lang.change('tr'); return false;"><img src="images/turkey-icon.png" alt="Türkçe" id="tr"></a>
        <a href="#english" onclick="window.lang.change('en'); return false;"><img src="images/uk-icon.png" alt="English" id="eng"></a>

    </div>
    <!-- Header -->
    <header>

        <div class="intro">
            <!-- Site Logo -->
            <div class="logo">IOTERM</div>
            <!-- End Site Logo -->
            <!-- Rotator Title -->
            <div id="rotate">
                <h1 class="rotate" lang="tr">
                    BİZ
                    <span lang="tr">NESNELERİN İNTERNETİ (IOT)</span>
                    <br>ÇÖZÜMLERİ
                    <br>ŞİRKETİYİZ,
                    <span lang="tr">BİZ IOTERM'ÜZ</span>
                </h1>

                <h1 class="rotate" lang="tr">
                    DAHA İYİ
                    <br>
                    <span lang="tr">BİR DÜNYA İÇİN</span>
                    <br lang="tr">BÜTÜNLEŞİK BİLGİ
                    <span lang="tr">SAĞLIYORUZ.</span>
                </h1>
            </div>
            <!-- End Rotator Title -->

        </div>
        <!-- Nav -->
        <nav>
            <ul class="navigation">
                <li class="link bottom move" id="iot_link">
                    <a href="#iot"><span lang="tr">IOT NEDİR</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="link bottom move" id="about_link">
                    <a href="#about"><span lang="tr">HAKKIMIZDA</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="link bottom move">
                    <a href="#contact"><span lang="tr">İLETİŞİM</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="link bottom move" id="solutions_link">
                    <a href="#solutions"><span lang="tr">ÇÖZÜMLERİMİZ</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="link bottom move" id="products_link">
                    <a href="#products"><span lang="tr">ÜRÜNLERİMİZ</span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <!-- End Nav -->
    </header>

    <!-- End Header -->
    <!-- About Section -->
    <section id="about" data-direction="from-right">
        <div class="content h4c">
            <a href="#" class="close"></a>
            <h1>
                <span lang="tr">VİZYON ve AMAÇ</span>
            </h1>

            <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 h4c">
                    <h4 lang="tr">Vizyon</h4>
                    <p lang="tr">IoTerm olarak biz, müşterilerimizin ihtiyaçlarını belirleyerek, onlara en uygun, optimize edilmiş IoT ürünleriyle, hizmet ve çözüm sunarken müşterilerimizin işlerine değer katarak üstünlükleri için çaba sarf ederiz.</p>
                    <h4 lang="tr">Amaç</h4>
                    <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
                        <li lang="tr">Organizasyonlara çözüm ortağı gibi hizmet vererek araştırma, geliştirme ve operasyonel çözüm ihtiyaçlarını belirlemelerinde yardımcı olmak.</li>
                        <li lang="tr">Teknolojik gelişmeleri yakından takip ederek şirketlere, işletmelere danışmanlık sağlayarak değer katmak.</li>
                        <li lang="tr">Şirketlerin, organizasyonların kendi çözüm ve ürünleri için doğru yöntemi belirlemelerinde yardımcı olmak ve bu süreçte etkin rol üstlenmek.</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h4 lang="tr">Çözüm Ortaklarımız</h4>

            <div class="row partnerRow">
                <div class="col-md-2 thumbnailImage">
                    <a href="http://www.bulutistan.com" target="_blank">
                        <img src="images/bulutistan.png" class="bulutistanImg" alt="Bulutistan">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 thumbnailImage">
                    <a href="http://www.datamarket.com.tr" target="_blank">
                        <img src="images/datamarket.png" class="datamarketImg" alt="DataMarket">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 thumbnailImage">
                    <a href="http://www.esq.com" target="_blank">
                        <img src="images/esq.png" class="esqImg" alt="ESQ">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 thumbnailImage">
                    <a href="http://www.libelium.com" target="_blank">
                        <img src="images/libelium.png" class="libeliumImg" alt="Libelium">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 thumbnailImage">
                    <a href="http://www.microsoft.com" target="_blank">
                        <img src="images/microsoft.png" class="microsoftImg" alt="Microsoft">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 thumbnailImage">
                    <a href="http://www.turkcell.com.tr" target="_blank">
                        <img src="images/turkcell.png" class="turkcellImg" alt="Turkcell">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>




        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- End About Section -->
    <!-- Solutions Section -->
    <section id="solutions" data-direction="from-left">
        <div class="container">
            <a href="#" class="close"></a>
            <h1>
                <span lang="tr">ÇÖZÜMLERİMİZ</span>
            </h1>    
            <div class="row solutionsRow">
                <div class="col-md-3 no-pad">
                    <h2 lang="tr" class="solutions">Akıllı Şehirler</h2>
                    <div id="right" class="pics">
                        <img class="img-center" src="images/smart-cities1.png" width="168" height="168" alt="Akıllı Şehir"/>
                        <ul class="solutions-ul">
                            <li lang="tr">
                                <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i> Akıllı Otopark
                            </li>
                            <li lang="tr">
                                <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i> Akıllı Aydınlatma
                            </li>
                            <li lang="tr">
                                <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i> Trafik Sıkışıklığı
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 no-pad1">
                    <h2 lang="tr" class="solutions">Akıllı Çevre</h2>
                    <div id="right1" class="pics">
                        <img class="img-center" src="images/smart-env.jpg" width="168" height="168" alt="Akıllı Çevre"/>
                        <ul class="solutions-ul">
                            <li lang="tr">
                                <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i> Hava Kirliliği
                            </li>
                            <li lang="tr">
                                <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i> Orman Yangın Algılama
                            </li>
                            <li lang="tr">
                                <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i> Deprem Erken Teşhis
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 no-pad">
                    <h2 lang="tr" class="solutions">Akıllı Su</h2>
                    <div id="right2" class="pics">
                        <img class="img-center" src="images/smart-water.jpg" width="168" height="168" alt="Akıllı Su"/>
                        <ul class="solutions-ul">
                            <li lang="tr">
                                <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i> Su Sızıntıları
                            </li>
                            <li lang="tr">
                                <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i> Nehir Taşkınları
                            </li>
                            <li lang="tr">
                                <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i> Deniz Kirlilik Düzeyleri
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 no-pad1">
                    <h2 lang="tr" class="solutions">Akıllı Ölçüm</h2>
                    <div id="right3" class="pics">
                        <img class="img-center" src="images/smart_meter.jpg" width="168" height="168" alt="Akılı Ölçüm"/>
                        <ul class="solutions-ul">
                            <li lang="tr">
                                <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i> Su Akışı
                            </li>
                            <li lang="tr">
                                <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i> Hazne Seviyesi
                            </li>
                            <li lang="tr">
                                <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i> Akıllı Izgara
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 no-pad">
                    <h2 lang="tr" class="solutions">Akıllı Tarım</h2>
                    <div id="right4" class="pics">
                        <img class="img-center" src="images/smart-agriculture1.png" width="168" height="168" alt="Akıllı Tarım"/>
                        <ul class="solutions-ul">
                            <li lang="tr">
                                <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i> Gübreleme
                            </li>
                            <li lang="tr">
                                <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i> Şarap Kalite Artırılması
                            </li>
                            <li lang="tr">
                                <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i> Meteoroloji İstasyonu Ağı
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>                    
                <div class="col-md-3 no-pad">
                    <h2 lang="tr" class="solutions">Endüstriyel Kontrol</h2>
                    <div id="right6" class="pics">
                        <img class="img-center" src="images/smart-industry.jpg" width="168" height="168" alt="Endüstriyel Kontrol"/>
                        <ul class="solutions-ul">
                            <li lang="tr">
                                <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i> İç Hava Kalitesi
                            </li>
                            <li lang="tr">
                                <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i> Sıcaklık İzleme
                            </li>
                            <li lang="tr">
                                <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i> Ozon Varlığı
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 no-pad1">
                    <h2 lang="tr" class="solutions">Acil Durumlar</h2>
                    <div id="right7" class="pics">
                        <img class="img-center" src="images/smart-security.jpg" width="168" height="168" alt="Acil Durumlar"/>
                        <ul class="solutions-ul">
                            <li lang="tr">
                                <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i> Çevre Erişim Kontrolü
                            </li>
                            <li lang="tr">
                                <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i> Patlayıcı ve Tehlikeli Gazlar
                            </li>
                            <li lang="tr">
                                <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i> Radyasyon Seviyeleri
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- End Solutions Section -->
    <!-- Products Section -->
    <section id="products" data-direction="from-left">
        <div class="container containerProducts">
            <a href="#" class="close"></a>
            <h1>
                <span lang="tr">ÜRÜNLERİMİZ</span>
            </h1>

            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row ">
                    <div class="col-md-12">

                        <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
                            <div class="carousel-inner">

                                <div class="row item active">

                                    <div>
                                        <div class="row ">
                                            <div class="col-md-4" id="img1">
                                                <a href="#"><img class="img-center" src="images/waspmote_pro_t.png" alt="waspmote" ></a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-4" id="img2">
                                                <a href="#"><img class="img-center" src="images/waspmote_exp_radio_board_2-375_t.png" alt="waspmote" ></a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-4" id="img3">
                                                <a href="#"><img class="img-center" src="images/u13_gw_t.png" alt="waspmote" ></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>    
                                    <div class="caption row ">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <h3 class="productHeight">Waspmote</h3>

                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row" id="desc">
                                            <div class="col-md-4" id="exp1">
                                                <ul style="list-style-type: none;" class="productSize">
                                                    <li lang="tr">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i> Tüm sensörlere bağlanabilir
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li lang="tr">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-rss"></i> Tüm wi-fi teknolojilerini destekler
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li lang="tr">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-cloud"></i> Bulut teknolojilerine uyumlu
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>

                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-4" id="exp2">
                                                <ul style="list-style-type: none;" class="waspmote">
                                                    <li lang="tr">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Ultra düşük güç (0.7uA)
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li lang="tr">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> 100+ Sensör uyumluluğu
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li lang="tr">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Kablosuz uzaktan programlama
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li lang="tr">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Şifreleme Kütüphaneleri (AES, RSA)
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li lang="tr">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Encapsulated line available
                                                    </li>    
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-4" id="exp3">
                                                <ul style="list-style-type: none;" class="waspmote">

                                                    <li lang="tr">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Desteklediği Protokoller: RS-232,RS-485,Modbus,CAN Bus, 4-20mA
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li lang="tr">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> 3G/GPRS/LoRaWAN/LoRa/Sigfox/868/900MHz,ZigBee/802.15.4/WiFi/RFID/ NFC/ Bluetooth 4.0
                                                    </li>    
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>    
                                </div><!-- /Slide1 -->
                                <div class="row item">    
                                    <div class="bannerImage">
                                        <iframe width="450" height="282" class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/GRMMS8nOdwc?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0"></iframe>
                                    </div>    
                                    <div class="caption row" id="yTube1">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <h3 lang="tr" class="productHeight" id="utube2">Waspmote Sensör Kartı</h3>

                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-12 waspmoteps1">
                                                <p lang="tr">Waspmote kartı için 50'den fazla sensör mevcuttur. </p>
                                            </div>   

                                        </div>
                                    </div>    
                                </div><!-- /Slide2 -->                                    
                                <div class="row item">

                                    <div class="bannerImage">
                                        <iframe width="450" height="270" class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/f1wXYGDvYAY?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0"></iframe>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="caption row" id="yTube2">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <h3 lang="tr" class="productHeight" id="utube1">Waspmote Tak ve Algıla</h3>

                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-12 waspmoteps" id="wspmote">
                                                <p lang="tr">Yeni Waspmote Tak ve Algıla geliştiricilerin elektroniğin zorluklarından kurtarıp sevislere ve uygulamalara odaklanmasını sağlar.</p>
                                            </div> 
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                    </div><!-- /Slide4 -->

                            </div>

                            <div class="control-box">
                                <a data-slide="prev" href="#myCarousel" class="carousel-control left">‹</a>
                                <a data-slide="next" href="#myCarousel" class="carousel-control right">›</a>
                            </div><!-- /.control-box -->

                        </div><!-- /#myCarousel -->

                    </div><!-- /.span12 -->
                </div><!-- /.row -->
            </div><!-- /.container -->

        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- End Products Section -->
    <!-- Contact Section -->
    <section id="contact" data-direction="from-bottom">
        <div class="container fill containerContacts">
            <a href="#" class="close"></a>
            <h1>
                <span lang="tr">İLETİŞİM</span>
            </h1>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <h4 lang="tr">BİZE E-POSTA GÖNDEREBİLİR VEYA AŞAĞIDAKİ FORMU DOLDURABİLSİNİZ. SİZE EN KISA SÜREDE GERİ DÖNÜŞ YAPACAĞIZ.</h4>
                    <!-- Begin Phone -->
                    <div class="newline col-sm-3 text-center">
                        <i class="fa fa-mobile fa-2x"></i>
                        <br>
                        +90 (530) 1407342
                        <br>
                        +90 (216) 6888616

                    </div>
                    <!-- End Phone -->
                    <!-- Begin Email -->
                    <div class="newline col-sm-3 text-center">
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-2x"></i>
                        <br>
                        contact@ioterm.com
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Email -->
                    <!-- Begin Address -->
                    <div class="newline col-sm-3 text-center">
                        <i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i>
                        <br>
                        IOTERM
                        <br>
                        İstanbul,
                        <span lang="tr">Türkiye</span>.
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Address -->
                    <!-- Begin Address -->
                    <div class="newline col-sm-3 text-center">
                        <i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i>
                        <br>
                        IOTERM
                        <br>
                        Boston,
                        <span lang="tr">ABD</span>.
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Address -->

                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <div class="contactForm">
                        <!-- Start Contact Form -->
                        <form id="contactForm" action="#" method="post" role="form">

                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input id="formName" type="text" class="input required" name="name" placeholder="Adınız" lang="tr">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input id="formEmail" type="email" class="input required" name="email" placeholder="E-posta adresiniz" lang="tr">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input id="phone" type="text" placeholder="Telefon numaranız" value="" size="30" name="phone" lang="tr">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea id="message" class="textarea required" name="message" rows="3" cols="40" placeholder="Sorunuz" lang="tr"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <button value="Submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-green-border btn-lg" type="submit" lang="tr">GÖNDER</button>
                            </div>

                        </form>
                        <div class="successMsg"></div>
                        <!-- End Contact Form -->
                    </div>    
                </div>    
            </div>    
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- End Contact Section -->
    <!-- IOT Section -->
    <section id="iot" data-direction="from-right">
        <div class="content containerIot">
            <a href="#" class="close"></a>
            <h1>
                <span lang="tr">IOT NEDİR</span>
            </h1>    
            <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

                    <p class="iot-font" lang="tr">Nesnelerin İnterneti (Internet of Things, kısaca IoT), fiziksel nesnelerin birbirleriyle veya daha büyük sistemlerle bağlantılı olduğu iletişim ağıdır.</p>
                    <img id="zoom" src="images/sw.png" data-zoom-image="images/sw_.jpg" width="450" height="253" alt="iot"/>
                  </div>
            </div>    
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- End IOT Section -->    
</body>
```

**EdiT 1:** You can check a different version without predefined 320x480 resolution on www.ioterm.com there is this code under @media only screen and (max-width: 767px)

`html, body {
    overflow-y: auto !important;
}`
If I disable it scrolling doesn't work. But if I add it to 320x480 media queries, it still doesn't work.

Comment: can you upload your website and share a working demo link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this code makes it work!

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
html, body {
    overflow-y: auto !important;
}

body {
    height: auto !important;
}

header {
    position: relative !important;
    top: auto !important;
    left: auto !important;
    right: auto !important;
    bottom: auto !important;
    min-height: 550px;
}

.intro h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
}

.intro p {
    font-size: 16px;
}

    .intro p span {
        width: 80px;
    }

section {
    position: relative !important;
    top: auto !important;
    left: auto !important;
    right: auto !important;
    bottom: auto !important;
    z-index: 2 !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}

    section .content, section .container {
        opacity: 1 !important;
    }

.navigation {
    display: none;
}

section {
    padding: 4em 0;
}

#solutions {
    padding: 0;
}

    #solutions h1 {
        background: none !important;
        height: auto;
        padding: 0px !important;
    }

.close {
    display: none;
}
```

}